# How to avoid API response data to store into cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was calling API with interval of 3 sec and API response which is too large, so I need to overcome the storage usage while API call. Can any one suggestion me what can I do? I tried it with adding cache headers but this is not working.

```
setInterval(async() => {
    let response = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT, {'cache':'no-store'});
    let result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  }, 3000);
```

Comment: Are you calling the same API endpoint or a slightly different one each time, because that's a weird API if it returns large amounts of different data every 3 seconds. If you are trying to setup paging I can help in an answer, but I need a little more information.

Comment: I am calling same API in every 3 second and API returns json response of around 2 MB data which increasing as time grows (but it will not be more than 3 MB). This API response is not garbage collected on browser side and increasing the memory usage in every 3 second by the response data size. So when my code runs for 1 hour on webpage then memory usage increased around 2 GB and due to less memory it got crashed. I tried setting cache as no-cache and no-store but doesn't work.

Comment: Well, if you're logging the Object then you can't garbage collect it. Try not to log it. Alternatively, just logging it's size or length is much less memory intensive.

Comment: Also, I'd consider creating a paging mechanism as 1MB/s average download is very inefficient, assuming it includes mostly the same data each time.

Comment: There is not same data each time.

Comment: I tried removing log, but while using data somewhere in code it is increasing the memory usage.